# Unable to install appium on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, selenium, appium, appium-ios, appium-android

I am trying to install appium on ubuntu but it is showning following error. Please help.

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/anubhavjain/.npm/_logs/2018-02-16T18_51_42_881Z-debug.log
```

Comment: How about reading what's there? Seriously, it even gives you a hint what's wrong!

Comment: What does `2018-02-16T18_51_42_881Z-debug.log` say?

Comment: I am new to ubuntu, can you please tell the command.

Answer (score 2):

The error message "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator." could contain the answer.Try this: `sudo npm install -g appium`